# Please update the moderator message template to include the code of conduct

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderator-templates

Now that the [code of conduct is rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), please edit the moderator tools to include that link in the template for rude and abusive warnings and suspensions.

The new code to me feels  much more well written than the current template which was great before we had a proper code for what being kind looks like in a global online community.

Consider taking some of the language from the code document and refreshing the mod message to have the words "CODE OF CONDUCT" in them for abusive and mean templates so it reinforces that we have a code no matter if the short links don't have the words "code" or "conduct" in them

Please and thank you

Comment: Probably worth noting that the existing links to /help/be-nice redirect to /conduct now; the templates don't need to be updated for that reason. Is there something specific you'd like to see changed in the wording?

Comment: Thanks @Shog9 I didn’t catch that redirect. For specifics, see the mod message I just now sent on Apple. I’d cut about half the words from the current template and explicitly change the text to say “code of conduct” somewhere in the first or second sentence.

Comment: Hmm... I gotta disagree with that approach, @bmike - putting critical guidance behind a link is an extra bit of friction between the guidance and the person who needs it. In particular, the "don't respond in kind" and "do flag if you see someone else behaving badly" bits really should be in the message itself. Ideally, the messages should *reiterate guidance users have already read*, not point them somewhere else.

Comment: Sounds good. As long as the links go to the conduct - that's the big ask I had. The wording is a matter of preference so I get how opinions can differ. What one things is overly wordy another will think is proper and thorough. Same with driving home a point - if you're going to warn someone, better to err on the side of thorough. I've removed my criticism of the length and made and edit so that this is about having the words "code" and "conduct" in the text of the body.